# D3JS. Динамическое добавление узлов в дереве

Tags: javascript, визуализация, d3.js

Это мое первое знакомство с js и с библиотекой d3js, так что не кидайте помидоры =)
Мне нужно, чтобы по клику по узлу дерева, к кликнутому узлу добавлялся дочерний узел. 
Проблема, как я понимаю, в свойстве узла depth и координатах, но как эту проблему решить пока не знаю...

Ссылка на код [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGnNZ/2/)

Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346

Comment: @eicto
Спасибо, помогло)